# How to import objects from another module as a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

in moduleA.py:

```
A = 1
B = 2
C = 3
D = 4
```

in moduleB.py, how can I achieve:

```
from moduleA import (A, B, C, D) as nums

for x in nums:
    print(x)
```

Comment: You can't do this with `import`.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Could the module provide a getter that returns the tuple you need?

Comment: Then what is the correct way to do it ? @Code-Apprentice

Comment: @doctorlove I don't need to import all the objects of the module, I just need to import some of them as a list and iterate over this list, is that possible ?

Comment: @AhmedAshraf This sounds like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). The solution depends on what the original problem that you are trying to solve.

Comment: The import statement provides no such feature

Comment: You can't "import as a list". You have to create the list, either in the module that is imported or in the module that is doing the importing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this the way you are trying to. You will need to find a different solution to your original problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
$ cat moduleB.py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import moduleA

for x in ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']:
        print(getattr(moduleA, x))

$ ./moduleB.py
1
2
3
4
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import a
from a import A,B,C,D

lst = [A, B, C, D]
print('List of nums from a.py is: ' + str(lst))

print('Elements in list:')
for x in lst:
    print(x)
```

Result:

```py
'''
List of nums from a.py is: [1, 2, 3, 4]
Elements in list:
1
2
3
4
'''
```